# create_category not taking variables as a name

Tags: discord.py

```
args = message.content.split()
category = await message.guild.create_category(args[1], overwrites=None, reason=None, position=0)
```

I'm trying to create a category with the name I got from a message, but nothing happened.

If I use this code it works perfectly

```
category = await message.guild.create_category("Category", overwrites=None, reason=None, position=0)
```

Note: the command isn't returning an error its just not creating the category

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're making commands, you should be using [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html).

Anyways, assuming that `args` is the text **after** the command, list indices start at `0`. Therefore, `args[0]` returns thr first argument, `args[1]` returns the second, etc.

Comment: I am aware its the second command argument that's why its the second on the list

Comment: Is it giving you any error message? If so, what is the error message saying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure it's a string value. You can do that by using `str(arg[1])`. Do this:

```
args = message.content.split()
category = await message.guild.create_category(str(args[1]), overwrites=None, reason=None, position=0)
```

Comment: I did print (type(args[1])) and got str, so I wouldn't need to convert it